# Django PasswordResetTokenGenerator, check_token(user, token) returns False on Production, Locally Works Fine

Tags: python, django, amazon-ec2

**Problem:** I'm using Django built-in class "PasswordResetTokenGenerator" to generate a token, For user account activation link, Which is sent to the user via email after submitting RegistrationForm.(I use Celery and RabbitMQ for Task execution and message queuing)

**views.py (RegistrationView)**

```
class MyUserCreationView(FormView):
    template_name = 'accounts/auth/register.html'
    form_class = MyUserCreationForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        user = form.save(commit=False)
        user.is_active = False
        email = user.email
        user.save()
        current_site = str(get_current_site(self.request))
        confirm_mail.apply_async((user.username, current_site), countdown=5)
        return render(self.request, 'accounts/auth/register.html', {'email': email})
```

**tokens.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.tokens import PasswordResetTokenGenerator
from django.utils import six

class TokenGenerator(PasswordResetTokenGenerator):
    def _make_hash_value(self, user, timestamp):
        return (
            six.text_type(user.pk) + six.text_type(timestamp)+ six.text_type(user.is_active)

        )

account_activation_token = TokenGenerator()
```

**tasks.py (Celery Task)** Sends Email to the user

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.utils.encoding import force_bytes
from django.utils.http import urlsafe_base64_encode
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

from celery import task

from ecommerce.settings.base import EMAIL_HOST_USER
from account.tokens import  account_activation_token

@task
def confirm_mail(user_name, current_site):

    user_obj = get_object_or_404(User,username=user_name)
    token=account_activation_token.make_token(user_obj)

    subject = 'Activate your MissIndia account.'
    message = render_to_string(
        'email/acc_activate_email.html',
        {
            'user': user_obj,
            'domain': current_site,
            'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user_obj.pk)).decode(),
            'token': token,
        }
    )

    mail_sent = send_mail(subject, message, EMAIL_HOST_USER, [
                        user_obj.email], fail_silently=False)

    return mail_sent
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path, re_path
from . import views
app_name = 'accounts'
urlpatterns = [
    re_path('confirm-email/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$', views.activate, name='activate'),
]
```

**views.py** (Activate account)

```
def activate(request, uidb64, token):
    try:
        uid = force_text(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))
        user = User.objects.get(pk=uid)
    except(TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, User.DoesNotExist):
        user = None

    if user is not None and account_activation_token.check_token(user, token):
        user.is_active = True
        user.save()
        # login(request, user)
        # return redirect('home')
        return HttpResponse('Thank you for your email confirmation. Now you can login your account.')
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Activation link is invalid!')
```

> **NOTE:** By Doing SSH into my EC2 instance, If i execute confirm_mail() function in tasks.py using Django shell commands It sends valid activation link.

Comment: Have you found the solution? I faced with the same behavior. Local and tests are working good, but on production, it tells me that token is invalid...

Comment: Not yet but I found a workaround. Now I'm calculating Token in django View and send that to Celery Task function as a parameter.

Comment: I have found the error. It seems that `six.text_type(user.is_active)` in some cases (when user.is_active = False) returns token that is wrong for further checking. 

The simple solution - avoiding boolean fields for tokens =)

Comment: Use-  six.text_type(user.pk) + six.text_type(timestamp)+ six.text_type(user.is_active)

Comment: After user open activation link, "user.is_active" changed to "True" which expires automaticaly the activation token.

Comment: I had this situation as well, local was succeeding but token generation wrapped in a task was failing in production.  Calculating the token outside of the task passes validation.  Navie guess is the timestamp change while in the queue?? as the is_active boolean makes sense in the hash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I fixed this problem By generating the token in the view and passing it to the celery task as an argument instead of generating it in Celery Task.

**View Code.**

```
class MyUserCreationView(FormView):
template_name = 'accounts/auth/register.html'
form_class = MyUserCreationForm

def form_valid(self, form):
    # This method is called when valid form data has been POSTed.
    # It should return an HttpResponse.
    user = form.save(commit=False)
    user.is_active = False
    email = user.email
    settings = SiteSettings.load()
    if settings.other_mail not in ('', None) and settings.domain not in ('', None):
        user.save()
        token = account_activation_token.make_token(user)
        confirm_mail.delay(settings.other_mail,
                           user.username, settings.domain, token)

        messages.add_message(self.request, messages.WARNING,
                             'We have sent an email with a confirmation link to your email address. Please allow 5-10 minutes for this message to arrive.', extra_tags='success')

        return render(self.request, 'accounts/auth/register.html', {'email': email})

    messages.add_message(self.request, messages.WARNING,
                         'Account not created, due to invalid site settings! Please Contact Admin.', extra_tags='danger')

    return render(self.request, 'accounts/auth/register.html')
```

**Celery task**

```
@app.task
def confirm_mail(from_mail, user_name, current_site, token):
    ses = AwsSes()
    user_obj = get_object_or_404(User, username=user_name)
    html_content = render_to_string(
        'email/acc_activate_email.html',
        {
            'user': user_obj,
            'confirm_link': urljoin(current_site, reverse('accounts:activate', args=[urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user_obj.pk)).decode(), token])),
        }
    )
    return ses.send_mail(from_mail, user_obj.email, 'Account activation.', html_content)
```

Answer (score 0):

in django newer versions, django.utils.six is removed
maybe you are using lower version in local development, and a higher version in production
if that is your case you have to options to fix it, make both the same older django version
or simply in terminal do:
pip3 install six
then in settings.py in INSTALLED_APPS add to the list:
'six',
now to import it instead of django.utils import six you will do

```
import six
```

directly